# Storing an array of chars in a queue?

Tags: c++, serial-port, c++98, mbed

I'm unable to quite search for what I want, as I am not sure how to address what I want to do, so I am just going to describe it. I think knowledge about mbed isn't really needed, since ill explain that part.

I have an interrupt function in my mbed program, which executes everytime there is input from serial link on pc.

```
Serial pc(USBTX,USBRX); //makes a serial link with pc

int main() {
    pc.attach(&newCommand);    //everytime input from pc is detected, this interrupt will make scheduler go to function called 'newCommand'

    //here, fetch one array of chars to work with, the oldest in the queue and analyse the command. If there is none available, wait for one to become available
}


void newCommand() {
    int inputCount = 0;
    int inputBuff[64];
    while (pc.readable()) {    //check if there is anything to read
        if (inputCount  < 64) // check for buffer overflow, maximum 64 ints
          inputBuff[inputCount] = pc.getc(); 
        else
          pc.getc();   // ran out of space, just throw the data away.
        inputCount++;
    }

    //store this char array (inputBuff) in a sort of queue, with the oldest at the front   
}
```

What sort of queue would I be looking for? I was thinking that maybe I can have a vector container which is global, which stores those arrays, and then the main program fetches the oldest one, but I am unsure of how to do this?

Edit: I guess I could also do a vector instead of array to store the chars, as in someVect.push_back(pc.getc()). Would that make it easier to store in a vector type queue?

Answer (score 0):

A vector of vectors would indeed be an option, but I think a fundamental problem would be that you'd expect the full command to be ready when a serial interrupt happens. This is not guaranteed.

Another way would be to use [BufferedSerial](https://os.mbed.com/users/sam_grove/code/BufferedSerial/) and use a separator (e.g. `\n`) between commands. Then just split the buffer by the separator character. Downside is that you need to poll, but would be straightforward to patch a callback into the library.